# Convert unstandardized strings to decimal

Tags: for-loop, coldfusion, switch-statement

I have a column in my table called `time_required`. It contains string such as 30min, 1H, 3 H, 5-6H,1/2 Day etc.. A bunch of unstandardized strings.

I need to convert these strings to a decimal value to standardize that table

- 30min would become 0.5,
- 1H would become 1
- 3 H would become 3
- 5-6H would become either 5 , 5.5 or 6

So far for certain value like 1/2 Day I did a switch case and simply converted that way :

```
<cffunction name="updateRealTime">
    <cfargument name="priorityID" required="yes">
    <cfargument name="realTime" required="yes">

    <cfquery name="qryPriorityList" datasource="NTCBF_PORTAL">
        UPDATE tblPriorityList 
        SET real_time = #arguments.realTime#
        WHERE priority_id = #arguments.priorityID# 
    </cfquery>
</cffunction>

<cfquery name="qry" datasource="#dsn#">
    <!--- not actual query --->
    SELECT * from tbl
</cfquery>


 <cfloop query="qry">
  <cfswitch expression="qry.time_required">
         <!--- 1/2 DAY --->
         <cfcase value="1/2 Day">
            <cfset convertedTime = 4> 
         </cfcase>
        <!--- more cases --->
        ...
        <cfset updateToRealTime(qry.ID,convertedTime)>
    </cfswitch>
</cfloop>
```

It was pretty easy and fast because I only had 6 different case in my table.
Now, the real challenge are the other 52 different entries (1H,30min, 3 H,...).
Would it be faster for me to a switch case like above and enumerate every possible case to do the conversion or there is a way more simpler way to convert all these data?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest storing the translations somewhere so you don't have to update programming code if a new value suddenly appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I thought I'd have a go as it sounded like an interesting problem! Here is what I've come up with:

```
<cfscript>
examples = [
    '30min',
    '1H 30minutes',
    '3 h 30 m',
    '1h 15m',
    '5 days 6 Hours 45 minutes'
];

for (it in examples) {
    minutes = 0;
    parts = rematchnocase('\d+ ?(d|h|m)', lcase(it));
    for (part in parts) {
        amount = reReplace(part, '[^0-9]', '', 'all');
        if (find('m', part)) {
            minutes += amount;
        } else if (find('h', part)) {
            minutes += amount * 60;
        } else if (find('d', part)) {
            minutes += amount * (60 * 24);
        }
    }
    
    
    fraction = (minutes % 60) / 60;
    hours = int(minutes / 60);
    decimal = hours + fraction;
    writeOutput('#it# is #minutes# minutes, which is #decimal# hours<br>');
}
</cfscript>
```

The output from running that gives you:

> 30min is 30 minutes, which is 0.5 hours
>
> 1H 30minutes is 90 minutes, which is 1.5 hours
>
> 3 h 30 m is 210 minutes, which is 3.5 hours
>
> 1h 15m is 75 minutes, which is 1.25 hours
>
> 5 days 6 Hours 45 minutes is 7605 minutes, which is 126.75 hours

The way I chose to approach it was to convert it to total minutes and from there I can convert to whatever I want. Hopefully that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Genius. Way shorter than my switch case with 50 different cases! Thank you!